# How I can cancel this white blank thing on the keyboard everytime when I click on a button

Tags: android, keyboard

hey when I click on the custom keyboard it shows me this blank thing I don't want to appear on every single time I click on a button how can I remove this thing it's on the picture if u see it u will understand me more and thanks for helping

[image]

CustomKeyboardView.class

```
public class CustomKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {

public CustomKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);
}

public void showWithAnimation(Animation animation) {
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    startAnimation(animation);
}
```

mainactivity.class

```
  private CustomKeyboardView mKeyboardView;
private EditText mTargetView;
private Keyboard mKeyboard;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard);
    mTargetView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target);
    mTargetView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            showKeyboardWithAnimation();
            return true;
        }
    });

    mKeyboardView = (CustomKeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);
    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);
    mKeyboardView
            .setOnKeyboardActionListener(new BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(
                    this));
}


private void showKeyboardWithAnimation() {
    if (mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(KeyboardWidgetActivity.this,
                        R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
        mKeyboardView.showWithAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

BasicOnKeyboardActionListener.class

```
public class BasicOnKeyboardActionListener implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

private Activity mTargetActivity;



public BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(Activity targetActivity) {
    mTargetActivity = targetActivity;
}

@Override
public void swipeUp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void swipeRight() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void swipeLeft() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void swipeDown() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onText(CharSequence text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    long eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime,
            KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, primaryCode, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE);

    mTargetActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
```

after setting findViewById for your keyboardview